# troubleshoot cpu usage mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds, amazon-ec2, cpu

We are running a few Mysql server on EC2 instances and RDS instances on AWS. From time to time they suddenly spike in CPU, and/or memory usage but when we login into the instances, it's too late and we can't troubleshoot the reason. Sometimes I am fast enough to see problem and run

```
show full processlist;
```

but it doesn't show any suspicious activity. slow logs and general logs show 0 info, and the mysqld log on /var/log/mysqld.log hasn't been updated in days, so I can't get any information from there as well.
so I would like to ask:

1. If I am currently seeing the spike on live, is there anything I can do to see what is exactly causing the problem? (maybe a query stucked, a locked table, or anything else that may happen)
2. If it's too late, and the spike happened when I was not seeing the monitoring, is there anyway besides the slow/regular logs where I could look?
3. I am replacing the last sysadmin who knew a lot about DBA on mysql, and I am not that familiar with mysql administration, so if you could recommend something for me to read/watch/listen, I really appreciate that.

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here. RAM on your Host server complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini Text results of: A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; C) complete MySQLTuner.com report if readily available - 7 or more days uptime is helpful Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps, ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, for server tuning analysis

Comment: Is the slowlog turned on?  Is `long_query_time` set low, say to `1`?